# multiple power supplies (5V, -12V, +12V) all on same board

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, pcb-design, integrated-circuit

I'm finishing up a pcb design and my specs just changed and I need to power an external sensor with +/-12V.  I previously had only been concerned with the voltages >0 but now I have to supply voltages <0 so my power supply system is changing...

I'm new to supplying multiple positive and negative voltages on a pcb.  The pcb is home to a 19 bit 22.1k samples/s adc so it requires some precision.  I am currently using an adm7150 to supply my PSoC 5lp, sram, adc, buffers, wifi module, sdcard, and reference voltages.

I was thinking of using a voltage inverter.. but I am weary because I don't want to lost accuracy by doing this.. does anyone have any suggestions on how to go about this.

the datasheet can be found here

www.bartington.com/Literaturepdf/Datasheets/Mag-03%20DS0013.pdf

and it states

Supply voltage                  ±12V to ±17V

Current consumption             +30mA, -10mA (+1.4mA per 100μT for each axis)

actual component suggestions are appreciated.. but I'll settle for anything I can get.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a low power consumption, a simple switched capacitors power supply will do. You can check at TI website. There are other providers (Maxim, Linear...) The sensor seems to have very good PSRR, so the design of the power supply seems to be not critical. Anyway, check carefully by yourself the parameters of the power supply.

EDIT: I found this one from Linear - LTC1044 - Most switched capacitor PS are for lower voltages.

Comment: appriciate the repsonse. Looking at the LTC1044.. it doesn't seem to meet my reqs, but after some quick seraching on the page I found several that seem too work.. Specifically LTC1144, and the LT1026. they both can supply the appropriate voltages.. but I am a little new to this and I am concerned with haveint different +/- voltages.. like having +15V and -13.5V due to voltage drop from the LT1144.  Is this something I Should care about as long as it remains above 12V?  thanks.